# Lombok builder pattern issue

Tags: java, lombok

I have added Lombok's JAR file in STS (eclipse).
I am using Lombok to create object using `builder()`. But, I am facing issue in inheritance.
If I am using Lombok's builder pattern to create objects it's working in workspace & in executable JAR file.
But, If I am using Lombok's builder pattern to create objects which [inherit](https://www.baeldung.com/lombok-builder-inheritance) another object, then it's not working.

```
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
class BaseEmp {
    private int a;
    private int b;
}


@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
class Emp extends BaseEmp implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Builder
    public Emp(int a, int b) {
        super(a, b);
    }

}

Emp emp = Emp.builder.a(ipA).b(ipB).build();
```

In this one when I am printing object, a and b values are `null` in JAR and working in STS.

But, when I converted to normal object creation in workspace and JAR, in both places it is working.

Means, upon compile, Lombok processor somehow misses inheritance class field.

Comment: You need to use `@SuperBuilder` if you want to create builders with inheritance.

Comment: I tried both SuperBuilder (which is in beta phase) & Builder for super class all argument constructor.

Comment: SuperBuilder didn't work on STS eclipse too. Anyway, that is not even stable. I can't use it for production

Answer (score 2):

If you extend another class, you should really think about using `@SuperBuilder`. Although it is still experimental, the Lombok maintainers made clear that this is mainly because it is a very young, extremely complex feature that will not receive support/bugfixes as fast as the core features. It is unlikely that `@SuperBuilder` will be redesigned or dropped in the future.

However, if you want to stick with `@Builder`, you must not have `@Builder` annotations on both the class and the constructor. Just put it on the constructor and it should work.

Furthermore, your superclass should also not have `@Builder`, otherwise you'll get a name clash on the `builder()` method. (You can work around that by renaming it using the parameter `builderMethodName`.)